# How to customize tumblr 404 URL not found page

Tags: html, css, tumblr

It seems Tumblr does not provide a div tag to customize the look and feel of the 'url not found' page.
Is there any way other way to customize the 404 (URL NOT FOUND) Page?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5):

### Edit: this method only works on tumblogs that don't have *pages*.

**Ask**, **Submit**, and other pages created in the Customize section will be detected as "not found" with this code.

---

## Description

Tumblr uses the normal `{block:Posts}` loop for static pages but without assigning any variables like `{PostID}`. If we use a class like `post{PostID}`, on <del>404 pages</del> *all static pages* we'll see a `.post` element, whereas on *posts* the elements will be something like `.post125678`

### Example

```
{block:Posts}
  <div class="post{PostID}">
    {block:Photo}all your blocks here{/block:Photo}
  </div>
{/block:Posts}
```

Using javascript:

```
var is404 = document.getElementsByClass('post').length;
```

Using CSS:

```
.post {
    /*this is a 404 page, customize it*/
}
```

### Cool javascript-less example

```
{block:Posts}
  <div class="post{PostID}">
    {block:Photo}all your blocks here{/block:Photo}
  </div>
{/block:Posts}
<div class="fill-me"></div>
```

In CSS:

```
.post { /*Hide Tumblr's 404 message*/
    display: none;
}
.post + .fill-me:before { /*use your message and style*/
    content: 'This page was not found!';
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

### Edit: Possible fixes

To fix this method, we should find a {tag} that is only shown on pages but not on 404 pages.

`{ShortURL}`, if it weren't buggy, could be used since in theory 404 pages shouldn't have a ShortURL.

I also tried `{Permalink}` but it behaves like `{PostID}` in this case.

Comment: Nice solution, however your answer is misleading. Tumblr doesn't provide a language string relating to 404 / not found: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/localizing_themes. The user would still have to input a message per language. Its also worth mentioning that the solution is IE9+.

Comment: I never said you wouldn't have to provide a localized 404 message, I only said the 404 page is detected **whatever the language** Tumblr displays the message in. Detecting a 404 page by looking up the English text "not found" only works in one language (or requires you to know and maintain a list of error messages in multiple languages)

Comment: I read **works in every language** and then saw the cool javascript-less example with the example in English only, so my bad. Again nice solution and worth the upvote.

Comment: I guess I should have been clearer, I edited the answer.

Comment: The `/ask` and `/submit` pages have no `{PostID}` either so this solution falls a bit short, as much as I love the pure CSS. Easy to add a class to the ask post though and avoid it with `.post:not(.<askclass>):not(.<submitclass>) + .fill-me:before` selector

Comment: Ouch, you're right. Those pages don't seem to have anything to discern them from a 404 page. I couldn't find an alternative solution. This will have to be a no-pages-blog solution. :(

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there isn't an official way to do this.

However, if your using javascript / jQuery, you could sniff for the following text:

> The URL you requested could not be found

Example jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p:contains(The URL you requested could not be found.)").html('YOUR TEXT HERE');
});
```

I would be more incline to add a class to the parent / body element so you can style the whole page differently.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Works for me */
    var text_posts = document.getElementsByClassName("regular");
    var text_404 = "The URL you requested could not be found.";
    var title_404 = "Not Found";
    if(text_posts.length == 1){
        var bodyNode = text_posts[0].lastChild;
        if(bodyNode.previousSibling.textContent == text_404) {
            // titleNode.innerHTML = "<a href='/'>Not Found</a>";
            var blog_loc = "http://" + document.domain + "/";
            var query = window.location.href.slice(blog_loc.length);
            var tokens = query.toLowerCase().split('/');
            var keyword = tokens.join(" ");
            var bodyContent = "Looks like you came from an old bookmark, or just looking for a page that doesn't exist. Were you looking for <span class='tg'><a href='/search/"+ escape(keyword) +"'>"+keyword+"</a></span>";
            bodyNode.previousSibling.innerHTML = bodyContent;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that the message is changed dependently on the visitor language

Answer (score 0):

I was research this problem too, and I found a answer.
If you gotta to 404 Error page, that post is no have any PostID,
so you can just check {PostID} is null or not to check it is 404 page.